# Browser-Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found

Tags: ionic-framework

When i try to deploy my ionic app to web, i get this error:

> cordova.js:866 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not 
>   SplashScreenProxy.js:131
>
> [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found SplashScreenProxy.js:131

Comment: is this for ionic 2/3 or ionic 4?

Comment: I have the same issue with v4

Comment: yeah its for v3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Splash Screen component is available only as Ionic Native component, so we can't use it inside browser, until ionic 4. Now, you can test in the terminal like this:

```
$ ionic cordova build browser
$ ionic serve --cordova --platform browser
```

After that config.xml is still not found, so I just copy to this folder:

```
$ cp config.xml platforms/browser/platform_www
```

Or just copy manually the file config.xml from your app folder and paste in the directory `platforms/browser/platform_www`

There will be another error on the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/screen 404 (Not Found)
```

This error is because on the config.xml file the value for SplashScreen is "screen" (or splash in older ionics)

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

If you change value for an image name, like "logo.png"

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="logo.png" />
```

and put that file in the same directory (/platforms/browser/platform_www) then you will get a splash image on the browser (I used chrome for this test and it worked)

Comment: In my case I am running from a test folder on my server but I get the error because whoever (ionic?) is trying to access it at the root 
GET http://64.52.109.104/config.xml  404 (Not Found)
How can I fix this and tell it to load relative to mydomain.com/TestFolder/index.html ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Angular that already has config.xml in /platforms/www, this is what worked for me.  Open up angular.json and look for the projects/APPNAME/architect/build/options/assets property and add an entry to tell Angular where to find config.xml.  Here is what my assets array ended up looking like:

```
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "assets"
    },
    {
        "glob": "config.xml",
        "input": "",
        "output": "/"
    },
    {
        "glob": "**/*.svg",
        "input": "../../node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
        "output": "svg"
    }
]
```

After that the splashscreen appears, but I get a 404 for "/screen" because of the config now looking for a splashscreen image that isn't there.  I don't want to change this for Android and iOS, but in the browser I just want to point it at an image, so I added the following node in config.xml, immediately **before** the SplashScreen preference (adding it after doesn't work).

```
<platform name="browser">
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="/assets/images/splashscreen.jpg" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenWidth" value="600" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenHeight" value="300" />
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

Note that I have to specify a width and height, which you don't need to do for Android or iOS.

You may need to run `ionic cordova prepare browser` to copy the config into the right folder (or manually copy it to /platforms/browser/www).

And voila!  That should do it.

Comment: This is a more permanent solution. Good stuff!